# rings in which every element is a sum of two commuting idempotents

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Is there a known characterization of the rings $R$ (containing $1$) with this property: **every element of $R$ is a sum of two commuting idempotents**.

Comment: May I ask where this question comes from? It is a very fun question, and I can solve it for finite rings. On the other hand, with the finite hypothesis, it would make an excellent challenging homework question for a class on non-commutative ring theory, and I'd rather not give away the answer if it is.

Comment: Anti-inverse rings, see http://journals.cambridge.org/abstract_S000497270002668X and http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/publ/53/n047p225.pdf (also http://www.math.okayama-u.ac.jp/mjou/mjou1-46/mjou_pdf/mjou_33/mjou_33_115.pdf is related)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are two commuting idempotents, then $(x+y)^3 = x+y+6xy$, $(x+y)^2=x+y+2xy$, so $z=x+y$ satisfies the equation $z^3-3z^2+2z=0$. Plugging $z=3$ into the equation, we obtain $6=0$. So the ring is a product of a ring of characteristic $3$ and a ring of characteristic $2$.

In the ring of characteristic $2$, $(x+y)^2=(x+y)$, so every element is idempotent. This implies that the ring is commutative, because

$$0 = (a+b)-a-b=(a+b)^2-a^2-b^2 = ab+ba = ab-ba$$

So the ring is a Boolean algebra - the ring of locally constant functions to $\mathbb F_2$ on a compact, totally disconnected topological space.

In the ring of characteristic $3$, as Clement points out the ring is commutative, because we have $a^3=a$, so if $a$ is invertible then $a^2=1$, so in the group of units every element has order $2$, so the group of units is commutative. But every element is the sum of two units: $a= (1-a-a^2) + (a^2-a-1)$, so the whole ring is commutative.

Being reduced, the intersection of all the prime ideals is $0$, but the field of fractions of a prime ideal is a field where every element is its own cube, hence is $\mathbb F_3$. So the ring embeds into a product of copies of $\mathbb F_3$. By the same logic as in the Boolean algebras case that the ring is the ring of locally constant  functions to $\mathbb F_3$ on a compact totally disconnected topological space:

Let $R$ be our ring, then $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is a topological space by standard ring theory. Since each prime ideal has quotien $\mathbb F_3$, and element $x\in R$ corresponds to a function from this space to $\mathbb F_3$. Since the sets $(x=0)$, $(x=1)$, $(x=2)$ are each closed, because they correspond to ideals, the function must be locally constant. Conversely, a locally constant function actually corresponds to an element of the ring since it locally looks like an element of the ring. The space is totally disconnected since each pair of distinct points must be distinguished by some locally constant function.

So the final answer is that such a ring consists of all the locally constant functions to $\mathbb F_2$ and $\mathbb F_3$, respectively, on a pair of compact, totally disconnected topological spaces. Conversely, any such ring will have every element the sum of two idempotents.

EDIT: In a ring where every element is the sum of $n$ commuting idempotents, every element will satisfy $\prod_{i=0}^{n} (z-i)=0$, so by plugging in $n+1$, we will have $n!=0$. So the ring will decompose as a product of $p$-power parts for $p\leq n$ prime. Mod $p^k$, each element which is the sum of $n$ idempotents satisfies $\prod_{i=0}^{\min(n, p^k-1)} (z-i)=0$. In particular, mod $p$ we will have $z^p-z=0$. So mod $2$ and mod $3$ the ring will still have the same form, but I think at some point (mod $4$? mod $5$? mod $7$?) it stops being necessarily commutative.

In the finite case, and the commutative case, things get simpler.

Comment: If the ring has characteristic 3, then your equation yields $z^3=z$ for all $z$ in the ring, which classically yields that the ring is commutative.

Comment: In fact, rings satisfying z3=z are I believe subdirect products of division rings. Since the only characteristic 3 division ring where each element is a sum of 2 commuting idempotents is Z/3, we get that the answer is products of copies of Z/2 and Z/3.

Comment: Benjamin, there are subdirect products of division rings that are not direct products of division rings. Consider the subring of $(\mathbb{Z}/3)^\mathbb{N}$ consisting of the ultimately constant sequences. It is not a direct product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/3$.

Comment: Ok, I had falsely assumed every subdirect product is direct for these rings.  (I fixed my comment).

Comment: @WillSawin, I just gave what I assume is an equivalent answer at the same time.

Comment: It is noteworthy that the property is actually equivalent to having $\forall z \in R, \; z^3=z$ !

Comment: @ClémentdeSeguinsPazzis, True.  Now we need the one line proof that avoids going through reduced rings etc.

Comment: Ok, I found the trivial proof.

Comment: How do you conclude that "the ring is a product of a ring of characteristic 3 and a ring of characteristic 2" ?

Comment: @user40021, I give the proof in the comments below my answer.

Comment: A question: Why is $1-a^2$ invertible?  I see how to invert $a^2+a-1$, since $(a^2+a-1)(1-a-a^2)=1$, but not $1-a^2$.  (Of course ultimately this is irrelevant as we can also show commutativity by other means.)

Comment: Also, it's probably worth noting at the end that the converse holds: Given such a ring as $R\times S$, where $R$ is characteristic 2 and $S$ is characteristic 3, we can decompose $(x,y)$ as $(x,y^2)+(0,y-y^2)$, and both summands here are idempotent.

Comment: The first two lines are very very nice. I wonder what happens if every element is a sum of three mutually commuting idempotents. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hi Will, I've just realized that the question I've posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013336/ is rather close to the question you've drive-by-answered in your EDIT. But I don't understand how you answered it. Why does the ring decompose as a product of $p$-power parts? (As a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, it does decompose this way, because the Chinese Remainder Theorem factors the ring $\mathbb{Z} / \left(n+1\right)! \mathbb{Z}$; but as a ring?) And how do you get $z^p - z = 0$ ?

Comment: Oh, I see why the ring decomposes. Namely, the Chinese Remainder Theorem factors the ring $\mathbb{Z} / \left(n+1\right)! \mathbb{Z}$ into a product of $\mathbb{Z} / p^k \mathbb{Z}$'s; if we take the idempotents in this ring corresponding to this factorization and send them canonically into our ring $R$, then the resulting idempotents in $R$ split $R$ into a corresponding product of $\mathbb{Z} / p^k \mathbb{Z}$-algebras.

Comment: I am slow today. Why is every element a sum of two units in the characteristic-$3$ case?

Comment: @darijgrinberg If we know $a^3=a$ then to check a polynomial in $a$ is a unit, it suffices to check it is invertible for $a=0, 1, -1$ as then it is invertible in the formal ring $\mathbb F_3[a]/(a^3-a)$. One can easily check that for these polynomials. It should also be possible to check directly that they are their own inverses by squaring and dividing by $a^3-a$.

Comment: @WillSawin: Ah! I didn't realize you could do the invertibility check already in $\mathbb{F}_3\left[a\right] / \left(a^3-a\right)$. Nice trick.

Answer (score 6):

**The trivial/elementary proof (in particular, it does not use the axiom choice).**

A ring $R$ satisfies your condition iff it satisfies the identity $x^3=x$.
Pf.
Will shows above with a short computation that if $R$ satisfies the condition, then the characteristic divides $6$.  So if $z=e+f$ with $e,f$ commuting idempotents, then $z^3=(e+f)^3=e+6ef+f = e+f=z$.

Suppose $z^3=z$ for all elements of $R$.  Now $R$ has characteristic dividing $6$ since $2=(1+1)^3=8$.  Thus we have $R$ is a product $R_1\times R_2$ of a ring $R_1$ of characteristic $2$ and $R_2$ of characteristic $3$.  The ring $R_1$ is boolean (using $z-1=(z-1)^3=z^3-3z^2+3z-1=z^2-1$, whence $z^2=z$) and so all elements are idempotent and we are done.  So it suffices to handle $R_2$, i.e., assume the characteristic is $3$.

Note $z^2$ is idempotent and $z=z^2+(z-z^2)$.  We claim the latter is idempotent.  Then $(z-z^2)^2= z^2-2z^3+z^4=2z^2-2z=z-z^2$.  Done.

**Answer.**
I believe that the answer is that the ring be a subdirect product of copies of $Z/2$ and $Z/3$, which in this case is equivalent to being in the variety of rings generated by $Z/6$.

My original revised answer below says that a ring satisfying the desired condition is a subdirect product of copies of $Z/2$ and $Z/3$ and hence in the variety generated by $Z/6$.

Suppose $R$ is a ring in the variety generated by $Z/6$.  Since $R$ is a direct limit of  finitely generated rings and your property is closed under direct limit, we may assume that $R$ is finitely generated.  But then $R$ is finite because a variety generated by a finite ring is locally finite.

But if $R$ is finite and in this variety, then $R$ is a reduced finite commutative ring and hence a finite direct product of domains belonging to the variety generated by $Z/6$.  But $Z/2$ and $Z/3$ are the only domains in this variety.

**Original Revised Answer.**
A necessary condition is that $R$ is a subdirect product of copies of $Z/2$ and $Z/3$.

Claim 1:  The class of rings satisfying your property is closed under direct product and homomorphic images.

Pf. Exercise.

Claim 2: If the ring is indecomposable (not a direct product), then the ring either is a boolean algebra or satisfies $z^3=z$. 
Pf. See Will's answer and the comments.

Claim 3: the ring $R$ is reduced (i.e., has no non-zero nilpotents).
Pf. Clear since it is a product of a ring satisfying $z^2=z$ and one satisfying $z^3=z$.

Theorem 12.7 in Lam's book on non-commutative rings shows a subdirectly irreducible reduced ring is an integral domain.  Since 0,1 are the unique idempotents of an integral domain, we conclude that $R$ is subdirect product of $Z/2$ or $Z/3$.

Now boolean algebras (=subdirect products of $Z/2$) all have the desired property so it remains to see which subdirect products of $Z/3$ have the property.

Comment: I am confused. Not every Boolean algebra is a direct product of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2$. (Or maybe I'm not sure what "direct" in direct product means.)

Comment: ok, I was hasty. I was thinking of finite subdirect products.  Let me fix.

Comment: Any subdirect product of $\mathbb{Z}/3$ has this property.  Any element $z\in R$ can be considered as a continuous function $z:\operatorname{Spec} R\to \mathbb{Z}/3$.  For $i\in\mathbb{Z}/3$, let $A_i=z^{-1}(\{i\})$.  Then these sets are clopen, and $z=1_{A_1\cup A_2}+1_{A_2}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey, this is Will's version of the argument.  My first version was to reduce to the finitely generated case, where the ring is finite and no Zariski topology is needed.  Now I have the elementary proof.

Comment: The proof can be simplified in one direction. My equation $z^3-3z^2+2z=0$ is just $(z-1)^3=(z-1)$.

Comment: @WillSawin, Thanks. My answer basically came from interacting with you and Clement and should be considered all our answers.

Comment: I don't think my argument uses commutativity anymore. The direct product decomposition comes because 1 is a sum of orthogonal idempotents in Z_6 and z commutes with its square.

Comment: How do you conclude that "Thus we have $R$ is a product $R_1\times R_2$ of a ring $R_1$ of characteristic $2$ and $R_2$ of characteristic $3$" ?

Comment: If the characteristic of $R$ is 2 or 3, we are done.  If the characteristic is $6$, then $1=3+4$ and $3,4$ are central idempotents of $R$.  Thus $R\cong 3R\times 4R$. The ring $3R$ has characteristic $2$ (note the identity of $3R$ is 3) and $4R$ has characteristic $3$ (it has identity 4).

Comment: My so-called ``trivial proof'' is the only one that does not use the axiom of choice (or at least the ultrafilter theorem).  To get a subdirect decomposition or to prove that reduced is equivalent to the intersection of all prime ideals requires some form of choice (namely the ultrafilter lemma).

Comment: @EricWofsey Would you explain how do you consider elements as continuous maps? That is an interesting point of view but I cannot see how you are doing that.

Comment: @user40021, look at Will's argument.  It is not hard to see that in a subdirect product of copies $Z/3$ each prime ideal $P$ is maximal and $R/P\cong Z/3$.  So we can identify $R$ with continuous functions $R\to Z/3$ via the Gelfand transformation.  I.e., we can think of Spec(R) as Hom(R,Z/3) with the topology of pointwise convergence and the each element of $r$ gives a continuous map by evaluation.